# How to use Kendo UI Grid for php?

Tags: php, mysql, database, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using Kendo UI for a web app in php; I'm trying to create and use a grid.

the code is:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

require ("config_inc.php");
require_once ("../ui/lib/DataSourceResult.php");
require_once ("../ui/lib/Kendo/Autoload.php");

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$result = new DataSourceResult('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx;charset=utf8', 'xxx', 'xxx');
$type = $_GET['type'];

$columns = array('id', 'lab_name', 'created_on', 'created_by', 'edited_on', 'edited_by', 'deleted_on', 'deleted_by');

switch($type) {
    case 'create':
        $result = $result->create('laboratory', $columns, $request->models, 'id');
        break;
    case 'read':
        $result = $result->read('laboratory', $columns, $request);
        break;
    case 'update':
        $result = $result->update('laboratory', $columns, $request->models, 'id');
        break;
    case 'destroy':
        $result = $result->destroy('laboratory', $request->models, 'id');
        break;
}

echo json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
exit;
}

function diaplayLaboratory() {

require_once ("inc/config_inc.php");
require_once ("ui/lib/DataSourceResult.php");
require_once ("ui/lib/Kendo/Autoload.php");

$read = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceTransportRead();
$read ->url('inc/laboratory.php?type=read')
      ->contentType('application/json')
      ->type('POST');

$create = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceTransportCreate();
$create ->url('inc/laboratory.php?type=create')
        ->contentType('application/json')
        ->type('POST');

$update = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceTransportUpdate();
$update ->url('inc/laboratory.php?type=update')
        ->contentType('application/json')
        ->type('POST');

$destroy = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceTransportDestroy();
$destroy ->url("inc/laboratory.php?type=destroy")
         ->contentType('application/json')
         ->type('POST');

$transport = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceTransport();
$transport ->create($create)
           ->read($read)
           ->update($update)
           ->destroy($destroy)
           ->parameterMap('function(data) {
                return kendo.stringify(data);
            }');

$labNameValidation = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelFieldValidation();
$labNameValidation ->required(true)
                   ->min(1);

$labName = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelField('lab_name');
$labName ->type('string')
         ->validation($labNameValidation);

$model = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModel();
$model ->id('id')
       ->addField($labName);

$schema = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchema();
$schema->data('data')
       ->errors('errors')
       ->model($model);

$dataSource = new \Kendo\Data\DataSource();
$dataSource ->transport($transport)
            ->pageSize(20)
            ->schema($schema);

$laboratoryName = new \Kendo\UI\GridColumn();
$laboratoryName ->field('lab_name')
                ->title(T_("lab_name"));

$command = new \Kendo\UI\GridColumn();
$command ->addCommandItem("edit")
         ->addCommandItem("delete")
         ->title('&nbsp;')
         ->width(250);

$grid = new \Kendo\UI\Grid('grid');
$grid ->addColumn($laboratoryName, $command)
      ->dataSource($dataSource)
      ->addToolbarItem(new \Kendo\UI\GridToolbarItem('create'))
      ->editable('inline')
      ->scrollable(false);

echo $grid ->render();

}

?>
```

with this I get only the data and I cannot delete, edit and create.

I have to get the data with a custom select (I don't want to show deleted item) and show only the lab_name.

When I update, edit or create I need to set also other field that I don't show in the grid. 
How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Use hidden columns and then you can use then in create and edit.

Comment: @R.K.Saini ok, and how can I create and edit using the fields passing manually the data?

Comment: You mean how you manage create and edit request on server side ? For  that you can change your switch statement for create and edit, $request object holds the data send from browser to server and here you can add your manual entry like created_by, edited_by and other stuff